# how to put variables into a long string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string a very long string I want to put variables intoit but i couldn't

```
string body = @"-----------------------------13254316446590
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""max_file_size""

100000
-----------------------------13254316446590
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""uploadedfile""; filename=""file.txt""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<!>C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Temp\lost\file.txt<!>
-----------------------------13254316446590--
";
```

I want to make the path and the file name variables
I know that's looks like a stupid question but I tried to put the ""+"" without success

Comment: "I Have a string" it sounds like i HAVE A DREAM :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `String.Format(...)` ?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Example:

```
DateTime dat = new DateTime(2012, 1, 17, 9, 30, 0); 
string city = "Chicago";
int temp = -16;
string output = String.Format("At {0} in {1}, the temperature was {2} degrees.",
                              dat, city, temp);
Console.WriteLine(output);
// The example displays the following output: 
//    At 1/17/2012 9:30:00 AM in Chicago, the temperature was -16 degrees.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `String.Format()`

```
String.Format("some string {0} other string {1}", path, filename);
```

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it can help you.